# Algorithm to Draw Rectangles Around Words in Images

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, image-recognition

Greetings Overflowers,

I need an algorithm to draw rectangles around words in images of scanned documents.
This algorithm needs not to be 100% accurate anyway.
Though, it is preferable to require the least of human intervention during its work.
No assumptions on scanned document before hands (unknown fonts and languages, might include tables and figures)

Any ready made solutions or resources on the matter ?

Regards

Comment: Most graphical libraries have built in routines to draw rectangles, it shouldn't be that hard. Of course, the difficult part is identifying what is a word. Perhaps you should ask about that instead? :)

Answer (score 0):

most OCR engines provide this kind of information. But if you don't want to use an engine OpenCV can be used for this but it will require model building and tuning.

OCR in OpenCV
http://blog.damiles.com/?p=93

That's a big step. In short this is a hard problem to solve and if you want to do it yourself it's going to take a good while to get it working. Most likely you should consider a 3rd party OCR package. Like Nuance.  I've use it and can verify it has exactly this type of information and a lot more.

http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/omnipage/index.htm

Comment: With I used Nuance years ago there was no c# sdk but it was pretty easy to make one. I imagine they have one by now.